# how to locate a hyperlink field

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, ms-access-2010, ado

I have an access 2010 table with a hyperlink field where i store the E-Mail adress of clients. Before I add a new E-Mail I want to check if the E-Mail address is already there. I try to use a locate statement like (delphi 2009; adoconnection, TADOdataset):

`if table.locate('ML_Link',NewAdress,[locaseinsensitive]) then`

This statement gives an error message with something like that the sequence is not allowed.

How can I search for hyperlink fields?

Comment: If you add a "unique" constraint to that field, then you could just insert without checking. You'll get an exception if the constraint is violated (i.e., when the address is already present). Catch the exception and handle however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the @ character is considered a special character.  I suggest you try splitting the address into two parts, email and domain for example, then search both fields as

```
if table.locate('email;domain', VarArrayOf([NewEmail, NewDomain]), [locaseinsensitive]);
```

You may also need to add variants to your uses clause, depending on your delphi version..

Comment: I think you are wrong, because it also doesn't work with URLs, not only E-mai llink. I believe that the cause is the hyperlink field.

Comment: Here are more details about the error message. It seems to be only a delphi internal exception. The original(german) text is as follows: 
Im Projekt VP 2 2. exe ist eine Exception der Klasse EOIeException mit der Meldung 'Die Reihenfolge kann nicht angewendet werden' aufgetreten."
Translation is like: " the sequence/order can not applied"

Comment: I think URLs may contain special characters as well.. take a look at this article.. http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826763  .  From what this article says, periods are a special character in access.

Comment: Keep in mind, when you use ADO to do a locate, it's basically creating a quick temp dataset.filter, so in that context, your special characters are introduced. My hunch is that you won't be able to use hyperlink fields and locate together.

Comment: Your hint on the article seems to be the solution. Belown down I found "When you use hyperlinks in Access, the hyperlinks are stored as modified Memo fields with a number sign (#) as a delimiter. "
As far as I remind you cannot do a locate with a memo-field. 
Remains a impressive number of not to use characters

Comment: I have had these sort of issues in the past, so I've always split out the email, domain, domain suffix, and use locate on the three.